# "Unix error in open: Permission denied" when upgrading a Tezos docker container to v14

Tags: node, archive-node

I have Tezos docker containers running using Docker Compose:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  tezos:
    image: "${TEZOS_DOCKER_IMAGE}"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "${RPCPORT:-8732}:${RPCPORT:-8732}"
      - "${PEERPORT:-9732}:9732"
    command:
      [
        "tezos-node",
        "--network=${NETWORK}",
        "--history-mode=${HISTORY_MODE}",
        "--max-download-speed=20485760",
        "--net-addr=[::]:${PEERPORT:-9732}",
        "--rpc-addr 0.0.0.0:${RPCPORT}",
        "--allow-all-rpc 0.0.0.0:${RPCPORT}",
        "--metadata-size-limit=unlimited"
      ]
    volumes:
      - "${VOLUME:-tezos-data}:/var/run/tezos/node"
      - "/opt/snapshots/tezos:/opt/snapshots/tezos"

volumes:
  tezos-data:
```

However, after upgrading an archive node from v13 to v14, using these settings...

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=mainnet-archive
VISIBILITY=private
NETWORK=mainnet
TEZOS_DOCKER_IMAGE=tezos/tezos:v14.0
TEZOS_UPGRADER_DOCKER_IMAGE=tezos/tezos-bare:v14.0
HISTORY_MODE=archive
RPCPORT=8737
PEERPORT=9737
```

..I get this error:

```
Current public chain: 2018-06-30T16:07:32Z.
Local chain data: 2018-06-30T16:07:32Z.
Updating the node configuration...
Aug 31 15:35:29.825 - node.main: FULL access to RPC enabled; this is very risky.
Aug 31 15:35:29.825 - node.main:   (addresses = [::]:8732, 0.0.0.0:8737)
tezos-node: Error:
              The data directory version is too old.
              Found '0.8', expected '1.0'.
              It needs to be upgraded with `tezos-node upgrade storage`.
```

After looking at the docs, I am trying to use `tezos-node upgrade storage` to upgrade the storage. When I modify my Compose file to the following using the information at https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/scripts/docker/entrypoint.sh and deploy it..

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  tezos:
    image: "${TEZOS_DOCKER_IMAGE}"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "${RPCPORT:-8732}:${RPCPORT:-8732}"
      - "${PEERPORT:-9732}:9732"
    command: tezos-upgrade-storage
    volumes:
      - "${VOLUME:-tezos-data}:/var/run/tezos/node"
      - "/opt/snapshots/tezos:/opt/snapshots/tezos"

volumes:
  tezos-data:
```

..I see the following error:

```
Current public chain: 2018-06-30T16:07:32Z.
Local chain data: 2018-06-30T16:07:32Z.
tezos-node: Error:
              Unix error in open: Permission denied
```

Can someone tell me why I am getting this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is due to the permissions of the node files in the docker volume.

To fix the problem, mount your volume and enter the container:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/sh -v <volume>:/var/run/tezos/node tezos/tezos:v14.0
```

Then change the permissions, and delete the lock file:

```
cd /var/run/tezos/node/
sudo chown -R tezos.tezos .
rm data/lock
```

You can then upgrade the storage with your docker-compose file or with the following command:

```
docker run -v <volume>:/var/run/tezos/node tezos/tezos:v14.0 tezos-upgrade-storage
```